# Autowire outbound RestTemplate's HttpEntity with inbound request headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

My Spring Boot application will take in a request and part of its processing flow is to fire off some other requests to other RESTful microservices and massage the responses before sending it back to the requester.

The flow looks like this:

```
Requester -> My Controller -> My Service -> Upstream Service
            [    My Spring Boot Scope   ]
```

I use a `RestTemplate` to fire off the request to upstream services.

The inbound request that Requester sends will contain some headers such as `Authorization` and `CorrelationID`, which I need to grab and copy into the outbound `RestTemplate` request, which I would like to find a more efficient way to perform.

What I'm thinking of is to define an autowired `Request`-scoped  `HttpEntity` bean  which is `Request`-scoped in my `Configuration` class which will read the incoming headers and inject it into the `HttpEntity` bean. But I can't quite figure out how to read the request headers in the `Configuration` class itself. I don't want to do it at the controller level because that means every team member implementing a controller will need to do this.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to accomplish this with the following code below. Key thing is that Scope has to be set to request with a ScopedProxyMode configured.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    private static final List<String> ALLOW_HEADER_LIST = Arrays.asList("correlationid", "userid", "accept-language", "loginid", "channelid");

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public HttpHeaders httpHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpServletRequest curRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = curRequest.getHeaderNames();

        if (headerNames != null) {
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String header = headerNames.nextElement();
                String value = curRequest.getHeader(header);
                if (ALLOW_HEADER_LIST.contains(header.toLowerCase())) {
                    log.info("Adding header {} with value {}", header, value);
                    httpHeaders.add(header, value);
                } else log.debug("Header {} with value {} is not required to be copied", header, value);
            }
        }


        return httpHeaders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, it would be better to use Apache Http client, from the inbound parameters(authorization, etc.) you could insert to the apache http client already.

```
post.setHeader("Host", "accounts.google.com");
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
post.setHeader("Accept",
         "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
post.setHeader("Cookie", getCookies());
post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
post.setHeader("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Well, I'm quite neutral to using HttpClient or RestTemplate, but what I'm actually asking for is a single location to do this, for which I would like to do it via a request-scoped injection in the application configuration class. We have a fair number of microservices and would like to avoid telling each team member to implement this themselves. Thanks.

Comment: Was the API keys or credentials in a configuration property?